# Get values of Display metrics in custom class

Tags: android

Using the following code:

```
public class Panel extends SurfaceView  {
    // ......
    // in one of the methods I want to call  
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    // ......
}
```

The problem is with the `getWindowManager()` method, I guess this method can be called only in activity, but I am not in the activity I am in my custom method called panel. How can I get the `DisplayMetrics` in my custom component ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the display metrics you have to do this.

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
```

Then you can do this.

```
Panel p = (Panel) findViewById(R.id.panel);
p.setDisplayMetrics(displayMetrics);
```

And have access to it in your custom view.

```
public class Panel extends SurfaceView {
    private DisplayMetrics mDisplayMetrics;

    public void setDisplayMetrics(DisplayMetrics displayMetrics) {
        mDisplayMetrics = displayMetrics;
    }

    void myFunction() {
        // do something with display metrics
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

You can get DisplayMetrics in the View by one of this methods:

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
((Activity) getContext()).getWindowManager()
    .getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
```

or

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
((WindowManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE))
    .getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
```